# Is it possible to interconnect PHP application and laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a php application and laravel application residing on different servers. I need to to send data from php application to laravel application. Is it possible to interconnect these 2 application and send data?

I have tried sending data using curl in PHP application:

```
$url ='ip/project/public/index.php/admin/update-item-status';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$item);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In laravel application:

In web.php file:

```
Route::match(['get','post'], 'admin/update-item-status', 'ItemsController@updateItemStatus');
```

In ItemsController.php:

```
public function updateItemStatus(Request $request){ 

        $data = $request->all();

        Item::where('description',$data['item'])->update('req_flag','1');
    }
```

Comment: Yes. You build an API in the application you want to connect to and let the other application use that API. There are plenty of tutorials and guides about building and consuming API's in both Laravel and in plain PHP.

Comment: Try doing the same with cURL is CLI and use verbose mode (-vvv) to see what actually is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can post data using `curl` or `GuzzelHttp` Here are the steps that you can follow.

Suppose, Your application hosted as below:

**Laravel:** http://xyz.domain

**Now in laravel app:**

1. Create a `post` route in `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::post('receive_data', 'CommunicationController@receive');
```

2. Define action `receive` in `CommunicationController` as below:

```
public function receive(Request $request)
{

    dd($request); // just to debug data.

    // do whatever you want.
}
```

**In PHP application:**

1. Create a `curl` request to post the data.

```
$url ='ip/project/api/admin/update-item-status';

$payload = json_encode( array( "item"=> $data ) );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194932/discussion-on-answer-by-vikash-pathak-is-it-possible-to-interconnect-php-applica).